# File uploading with Dragonfly, impossible to access images after upload (Rails 3)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, dragonfly-gem

I'm trying to make a multiple drag and drop upload file system with Rails 3 and Dragonfly (or anything that would work actually)

I'm at the point where my file comes in my controller through the params hash and I can retrieve it as an ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile so I thought all I would have to do then is push it in my model's attribute image but it doesn't work

This my Picture model :

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
   image_accessor :image
   attr_accessible :image_name, :image_uid, :title
end
```

I thought this would work in my controller :

def createImage

```
@new_picture = Picture.new
@new_picture.image = params[:pic]

if @new_picture.save
  render :json => { :picture => @new_picture }
end
```

end
Ok, so this registers the record with image_name nil oddly, but with the image_uid set

However, when I try to access my image <%= image_tag @picture.image.url %> I get a not found error

For example :

```
Request     URL:http://localhost:3000/media/BAhbBlsHOgZmSSIhMjAxMi8wOS8yMi8xOV8zMF8yOF83MzBfZmlsZQY6BkVU
Request Method:GET
Status Code:404 Not Found
```

I'm using ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3.2.8

Any ideas ? :D

Answer (score 0):

Dragonfly needs to load it's rack adapter before it is able to take encoded url requests (like the one above). The best way to load it is to add this before `config.encoding = "utf-8` in your `/config/application.rb`

```
config.middleware.insert 0, 'Rack::Cache', {:verbose     => true,:metastore   => URI.encode("file:#{Rails.root}/tmp/dragonfly/cache/meta"),:entitystore => URI.encode("file:#{Rails.root}/tmp/dragonfly/cache/body")} unless Rails.env.production?
config.middleware.insert_after 'Rack::Cache', 'Dragonfly::Middleware', :images
```

Please note that you will need the Rack-Cache gem as well.

Hope this helps!